# Force a div height to a big font-size inside it

Tags: css, html, height

I have the following code:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="top">TOP TEXT
   </div>
   <div id="middle">MIDDLE TEXT
   </div>
   <div id="bottom">BOTTOM TEXT
   </div>
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
#top { font-size: 13px;}
#middle { font-size: 40px;}
#bottom { font-size: 10px;}
```

As you can see, the font size are very differents. The problem is that the divs doesn't appear correctly, because the font size are so big, making the texts appear over the others. The divs doesn't adjust the heights....I tried with height: auto, I tried changing the divs for spans, with overflow: visible...but I can't find a solution.
How can I force the div to adjust his height to the big font size?

**THE SOLUTION:
Thank you everybody for your ideas. In fact, Shredder, who gives me the link to jsfiddle....show me that the problem is not there. I found some css on the BODY tag that make the problem:**

```
body {font: 75%/125% arial,sans-serif;}
```

**as you can see, this "75%/125%" change the font-height....so there is the problem...
thank you so much!**

Comment: So you want all divs to be the same height or are you saying they are overlapping?

Comment: Rodrigo, I don't see any problems! Maybe you need to show us a live page so we (I ?) can understand your claim.

Comment: I don't see any problems http://jsfiddle.net/Us7HE/

Comment: thank you...when you don't see problems, means that the problem doesn't there...so please read the solution on the editted question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text should not overlap If you just have the css and html shown, divs expand to suit their content. With the limited information provided, it could possibly be one of the following (amongst others):
- the height or max-height of the divs is being set somewhere in your css,
- the divs are placed using position:absolute somewhere in your css

Answer (score 1):

Use 'em' and 'pc' to define your sizes rather than pixels.

This has some side effects, but overall it'll let you use relative size (ie. 1.2em [120% of font height]) as div height and it'll increase as the size of the font increases.

You can also use this to set input sizes, etc. (pc or picas is the width of the font).

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't your problem, but for others that arrive here: Divs won't expand for their text content if a parent (like body) has the line height set to a small(er) value.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, this problem isn`t caused by your code. 
You are right, that this part of code was responsible for your problem.

```
body {font: 75%/125% arial,sans-serif;}
```

BUT 
the font property and its attribute 75%/125% does change the line-height of the specified div and its children not the font-height.
Your line-height should be set to 100% or bigger otherwise text with bigger font-sizes can overlap the set line-height.